# Laravel Illuminate\Http\Request::input() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to call:  session(['cor_id' => **Request::input('cor_id')]);** on a create function in my controller, but I'm getting the following error: (I am using Laravel 6)

> Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::input() should not be called statically

Any assistance how to best solve this in correct way

Comment: Easily use $request->input('core_id') to get data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to be using the Facade, `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` also available as `Request`, if you want to call the method statically like that, since that Facade is the static proxy for the Request, `Illuminate\Http\Request`, instance.

```
use Request;
// or
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

Request::input(...);
```

Otherwise you probably want to be using an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` since you can have it injected into your Controller methods:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function something(Request $request, ...)
{
    ...
    session(['cor_id' => $request->input('cor_id')]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: same I have tried your solution and it is working as well

Answer (score 1):

[input](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_input) method for request class is not a static method, you should call it from request instance.

you can get the current request using  `app('request')` like this:

```
 $currentRequest =app('request')
session(['cor_id' => $currentRequest->input('cor_id')]);
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and it is working

Answer (score 1):

> Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::input() should not be called statically

Method `Illuminate\Http\Request::input()` should be called:

```
$request->input('cor_id');
```

Ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-input